# How to give tasks a name in Azure DevOps Pipelines (YML)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

In the pipelines.yml file, the following is used:

```
steps:
# Print buildId
- script: |
    echo "BuildId = $(buildId)"
```

When looking at the build log in Azure DevOps, I see just "CmdLine".

[image: TaskName]

Is there a way to give a **step** or a **script** a readable name which is visible in the build log?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to add the parameter `displayName`:

```
steps:
- script: 'echo "BuildId = $(Build.BuildId)"' 
  displayName: Test1001

- script: 'echo "BuildId = $(Build.BuildId)"' 
  displayName: Test1002
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine indeed, however I was mislead by VS2017 because the syntax highlighting failed. See this image : https://imgur.com/a/jgXH6t2

Comment: @Stef Heyenrath: Seems to be fixed in 2019, but for 2017, try moving displayName above script.